# Divide 2 columns from 2 different dataframes

Tags: r, dplyr

Does anybody know how to divide two columns from two different dataframes when there are multiple columns to id from?

Example:

```
library(dplyr)
  name <- c('A','A', 
            'B','B')
  month = c("oct 2018", "nov 2018", 
            "oct 2018",  "nov 2018")
  var1 = c("99", "99", 
            "99",  "99")
  value <- seq(1:length(month))
  df1 = data.frame(name, month, var1, value)

  df2 = df1
  df2["var1"] = c("992", "992", "992", "992")
  df2["value"] = c(2, 4, 6, 8)

  df1

  df2
```

Output

```
> df1
  name    month var1 value
1    A oct 2018   99     1
2    A nov 2018   99     2
3    B oct 2018   99     3
4    B nov 2018   99     4

> df2
  name    month var1 value
1    A oct 2018  992     2
2    A nov 2018  992     4
3    B oct 2018  992     6
4    B nov 2018  992     8
```

Does anybody know how to create a new dataframe that divides the "value"-column in df2 by the value column of df1? The method should be possible to use also when there are more columns than in the current example.

Comment: So, `df2$value / df1$value`?

Comment: Or if you want a `data.frame` as output: `df2["value"] / df1["value"]` Both dataframes must have the same number of columns.

Comment: I think an issue using this in my real problem, is that the rows are not sorted equally in the two dataframes, so when applying your suggested solutions worong results are produced.

Comment: is there a common identification for what should be divided e.g. 'name' and 'month'? then I would do a merge (first) and just divide the two columns as propsed by @markus

Comment: @WD11: All columns except for "var1" and "value" must be used for identification. How would you merge?

Comment: check ?merge - which is basically a join, or use join from tidyverse  … 
new.df <- merge(x = df1, y = df2, by = …); then you will end up with two value columns

Comment: `df3 <- merge(df1, df2, by = c("name", "month"))` and then do `df3$value.x/df3$value.y` ?

Comment: @RonakShah: That actaully fixes it. Thank you so much! A side question: I am making some boxplots, and I want to use the "var1" variable as fill. However, now there is "var1.x" and var1.y". Anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: yes, that is because `var1` value is different for `df1` and `df2` dataframes.

Comment: Indeed. What I think I need is a new variable "var1" in df3 which takes the correct values from "var1.x" and "var1.y". But then I will probably have to melt df3 first or something..

Comment: @KJA How would you know which is the correct value ?

Comment: @RonakShah: Sorry, ignore my latest question. I was a little confused. Thanks for helping anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In base R, we can do `merge`

```
df3 <- merge(df1, df2, by = c("name", "month")) 
df3$value <- df3$value.x/df3$value.y
df3
#  name    month var1.x value.x var1.y value.y value
#1    A nov 2018     99       2    992       4   0.5
#2    A oct 2018     99       1    992       2   0.5
#3    B nov 2018     99       4    992       8   0.5
#4    B oct 2018     99       3    992       6   0.5
```

You can drop `value.x` and `value.y` column if they are not needed.

Answer (score 1):

Join the two data frames together and then perform the division and drop unwanted columns that were generated by the join (assuming you want computed `value` column to replace the `value` columns from the original data frames).  Depending on what you want you may need a different `*_join`.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  inner_join(df2, by = c("name", "month")) %>% 
  mutate(value = value.x / value.y) %>%
  select(-value.x, -value.y)
```

giving:

```
  name    month var1.x var1.y value
1    A oct 2018     99    992   0.5
2    A nov 2018     99    992   0.5
3    B oct 2018     99    992   0.5
4    B nov 2018     99    992   0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `data.table` as well to do a join and create the column 'value' by dividing the 'value' column by the corresponding column in the other dataset while joining `on` 'name' and 'month'

```
library(data.table)
df3 <- copy(df1)
setDT(df3)[df2, value := value/i.value, on = .(name, month)]
df3
#   name    month var1 value
#1:    A oct 2018   99   0.5
#2:    A nov 2018   99   0.5
#3:    B oct 2018   99   0.5
#4:    B nov 2018   99   0.5
```